# JSON в Андроид Java

Tags: java, android, json

У меня в андроид приложении есть JSONObject мне нужно из этого обьекта взять все значения при этос я ключи не знаю. Можно его перевести в обычный массив и тд?

Answer (score 4):

У инстанса JSONObject есть метод keys(), который возвращает итератор ключей. Собственно:

```
Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
while( keys.hasNext() ) {
String key = keys.next();
...
}
```